# Generating PDF from specific pages of a Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, pdf-generation

I am able to generate PDF from an entire worksheet.

I want to generate PDF from specific pages on a worksheet using Excel VBA.

I want to give a range pages, say 3 to 5 and generate a PDF from only these pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Workbook class exposes an [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat) method that has parameters for *From* page and *To* page. This sounds like what you want.

There's an example macro [here](https://www.contextures.com/excelvbapdf.html) that shows how to export a specific sheet. You should be able to adapt this macro by calling ExportAsFixedFormat on the Workbook instead of the Worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You might also choose to set the PrintArea option to just the bits you want to print? That might be a simple work-around.